Use a dynamic module of nestjs over multiple projects
I have a nestjs project with bullmq and ioredis. I wanted to create a module and service which will have bullmq for storing data in queue and i wanted to use this module over multiple projects by passing redis configuration and queueName.
for that i have aproject with below files
client.module.ts
import { DynamicModule, Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bullmq';
import { HypersignMailClient } from './mail-client.service';

interface HypersignMailClientModuleOptions {
  redis?: {
    host: string;
    port: number;
  };
  queueName?: string;
}

@Global()
@Module({})
export class HypersignMailClientModule {
  static forRoot(options?: HypersignMailClientModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    const { redis, queueName } = options;
    return {
      module: HypersignMailClientModule,
      imports: [
        BullModule.forRoot({
          connection: redis || { host: "localhost", port: 6379 },
        }),
        BullModule.registerQueue({
          name: queueName || 'mail',
        }),
      ],
      providers: [HypersignMailClient],
      exports: [HypersignMailClient],
    }
  }
}


client.service.ts
  import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Queue } from 'bullmq';
@Injectable()
export class HypersignMailClient {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('mail') private readonly queue: Queue) { }
  async addJobsInBulk(
    jobs: { serverName: string; to: string; subject: string; message: any }[],
  ) {
    Logger.log('addJobsInBulk() method starts', 'HypersignMailClient');
    const bulkJobs = jobs.map((job) => ({
      name: 'sendMail',
      data: {
        serverName: job.serverName,
        to: job.to,
        subject: job.subject,
        message: job.message,
      },
    }));
    await this.queue.addBulk(bulkJobs);
  }
}


index.ts
export * from './mail-client.module';
export * from './mail-client.service';


ad then i have another nestjs project with very basic sructure i wanted to use above mentioned module in new project for that i have installed above project using yarn pathname.
in my app.module I have
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { HypersignMailClientModule } from 'hypersign-mail-client-nest';

@Module({
  imports: [HypersignMailClientModule.forRoot({})],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }


when I run the project I am getting below error
- Is BullModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current BullModule?
- If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BullModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
  })```
In second project i need not need to import or use any package of bull.


can any one tell me what i am doing wrong. How I could fix this issue.
Thanks in advance



